# What does it actually means "make 2013 his year"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It seems simple, but bit confused.

He wanted to make 2013 his year, to return to the top of the mountain, 
he tries to do that tonight's game.

In this sentence, "wanted 2013 his year" means 
"he could not be super happy in 2013"?
Therefore, the following goes and means,
"he tries to return to the top of the mountain(=get the title)
tonight's game."

Is this understanding correct??

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.  Note, your question is not clear enough to be answered here or elsewhere.  Do you have a reference to the original source of the phrase?  (Please edit the question if so.)

Answer (score 3):

"Make 2013 his year" means make 2013 the year in which he has a great success. The follow on phrase: "return to the top of the mountain" conveys the same sense -- of being successful, though this latter phrase implies that he was successful in the past, lost success and aspires to regain it. This implication is not present in "make 2013 his year".

So I believe your understanding is not correct. The two phrases both have the meaning of "make oneself very successful", with a few subtle differences.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How come does the sentence in the past tense "wanted"(to make 2013 his year)? Because of "wanted", I thought he could NOT make 2013 his year...

Answer (score 1):

*'To make it ones year'* is an idiom conveying the idea that a person will achieve or accomplish more that year. 
The same can be said for; Day, Week and Month.

It's more common to hear somebody say in response to some news or fortuitous event, *"that's just made my day"*

*'It's not been my year',* ofcourse has the opposite meaning, conveying a sense of prolonged misfortune and misery etc.